# Update a specific row in a database table

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am making a password vault gui app using tkiner. I am trying to add a function that lets me edit and update any specific line in the gui. What I mean is similar to how the remove_entry function can delete the line it is on, I want the edit_password function to edit any it is on. Additionally, I want the save_new_password function to update the vault table in the database.

Here are the functions I am referring to:

```
def remove_entry(input):
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM vault WHERE id = ?", (input,))
        db.commit()
        password_vault()
```

```
def edit_password():
        text1.config(state="normal")
        text2.config(state="normal")
        text3.config(state="normal")
        text4.config(state="normal")
```

```
 def save_new_password():
                website = str(text1.get("1.0", "end"))
                username = str(text2.get("1.0", "end"))
                password = str(text3.get("1.0", "end"))
                day = str(text4.get("1.0", "end"))
                insert_fields = """UPDATE vault (website,username,password, day)
                        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"""
                cursor.execute(insert_fields, [website, username, password, day])
                db.commit()
                text1.config(state="disabled")
                text2.config(state="disabled")
                text3.config(state="disabled")
                text4.config(state="disabled")
                password_vault()
```

Here is my code for reference:

```
import sqlite3
import hashlib
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from tkinter import simpledialog

with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS master(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
password TEXT NOT NULL);
""")

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vault(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
website TEXT NOT NULL,
username TEXT NOT NULL,
password TEXT NOT NULL,
day TEXT NOT NULL);
""")


def popup(text):
    answer = simpledialog.askstring("input string", text)

    return answer


window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")


def hashed_master_password(input):
    hash = hashlib.sha512(input).hexdigest()
    return hash


def setup():
    window.geometry("400x400")

    setup_password = tk.Label(window, text="Create master password")
    setup_password.config(anchor="e")
    setup_password.pack()

    create_password = tk.Entry(window, width=20)
    create_password.focus()
    create_password.pack()

    setup_label = tk.Label(window, text="Re-enter password")
    setup_label.pack()

    confirm_password = tk.Entry(window, width=20)
    confirm_password.pack()

    fail_to_match = tk.Label(window)
    fail_to_match.pack()

    def save_password():
        if create_password.get() == confirm_password.get():
            hashed_password = hashed_master_password(create_password.get().encode("UTF-8"))
            insert_password = """INSERT INTO master(password) VALUES(?)"""
            cursor.execute(insert_password, [hashed_password])
            db.commit()
            password_vault()
        else:
            fail_to_match.config(text="Passwords do not match")

    setup_button = tk.Button(window, text="set password", command=save_password)
    setup_button.pack()


def login_screen():
    window.geometry("500x500")

    master_password = tk.Label(window, text="Enter Master Password")
    master_password.config(anchor="e")
    master_password.pack()

    enter_password = tk.Entry(window, width=20, show="*")
    enter_password.focus()
    enter_password.pack()

    fail_label = tk.Label(window)
    fail_label.pack()

    def get_master_password():
        check_hash_password = hashed_master_password(enter_password.get().encode("UTF-8"))
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM master WHERE id=1 AND password = ?", [check_hash_password])
        return cursor.fetchall()

    def check_password():
        match = get_master_password()

        if match:
            password_vault()
        else:
            enter_password.delete(0, "end")
            fail_label.config(text="Wrong Password")

    pass_check_button = tk.Button(window, text="Submit", pady=5, command=check_password)
    pass_check_button.pack()


def password_vault():
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    def add_entry():
        website1 = "website"
        username1 = "username"
        password1 = "password"
        days1 = "days password is good for"

        website = popup(website1)
        username = popup(username1)
        password = popup(password1)
        day = popup(days1)

        insert_fields = """INSERT INTO vault(website,username,password, day)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"""
        cursor.execute(insert_fields, (website, username, password, day))
        db.commit()

        password_vault()

    def remove_entry(input):
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM vault WHERE id = ?", (input,))
        db.commit()
        password_vault()

    window.geometry("1550x700")
    main_frame = Frame(window)
    main_frame.grid(sticky="news")
    my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame, height=700, width=1525)
    my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=9, sticky='news')
    my_canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=10)
    my_frame = Frame(my_canvas, bd=1, relief="solid")
    my_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=my_frame, anchor="nw")

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(main_frame, command=my_canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=10, sticky="ns")

    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    my_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))

    def edit_password():
        text1.config(state="normal")
        text2.config(state="normal")
        text3.config(state="normal")
        text4.config(state="normal")

    vault_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Welcome to your password vault", font=("Time New Roman", 20))
    vault_label.grid(column=1, row=0)

    add_button = tk.Button(my_frame, text="Add new info", command=add_entry)
    add_button.grid(column=0, padx=8)

    website_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Website")
    website_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=80)

    username_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Username")
    username_label.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=80, pady=8)

    password_label = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Password")
    password_label.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=80)

    days_password_is_good_for = tk.Label(my_frame, text="Days password is good for")
    days_password_is_good_for.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=80)

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
    if cursor.fetchall() is not None:
        i = 0

        while True:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vault")
            array = cursor.fetchall()
            text1 = tk.Text(my_frame)
            text1.insert("1.0", array[i][1])
            text1.config(height=1, width=20, state="disabled")
            text1.grid(column=0, row=i+4)
            text2 = tk.Text(my_frame)
            text2.insert("1.0", array[i][2])
            text2.config(height=1, width=20, state="disabled")
            text2.grid(column=1, row=i+4)
            text3 = tk.Text(my_frame)
            text3.insert("1.0", array[i][3])
            text3.config(height=1, width=20, state="disabled")
            text3.grid(column=2, row=i+4)
            text4 = tk.Text(my_frame)
            text4.insert("1.0", array[i][4])
            text4.config(height=1, width=20, state="disabled")
            text4.grid(column=3, row=i+4)

            delete_button = tk.Button(my_frame, text="Delete", command=partial(remove_entry, array[i][0]))
            delete_button.grid(column=4, row=i+4, pady=8, padx=10)

            edit_button = tk.Button(my_frame, text="Update information", command=edit_password)
            edit_button.grid(column=5, row=i+4, pady=8, padx=10)

            def save_new_password():
                website = str(text1.get("1.0", "end"))
                username = str(text2.get("1.0", "end"))
                password = str(text3.get("1.0", "end"))
                day = str(text4.get("1.0", "end"))
                insert_fields = """UPDATE vault (website,username,password, day)
                        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"""
                cursor.execute(insert_fields, [website, username, password, day])
                db.commit()
                text1.config(state="disabled")
                text2.config(state="disabled")
                text3.config(state="disabled")
                text4.config(state="disabled")
                password_vault()

            password_save_button = tk.Button(my_frame, text="Save your updated information",
                                             command=save_new_password)
            password_save_button.grid(column=6, row=i+4, pady=8, padx=10)

            i = i+1

            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM VAULT")
            if (len(cursor.fetchall()) <= i):
                break


cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM master")

if cursor.fetchall():
    login_screen()
else:
    setup()

window.mainloop()
```

the main issues are edit_password only lets me edit the last row, and save_new_password gives me this error

cursor.execute(insert_fields, [website, username, password, day])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably mixing syntax for insert and updates. When issuing an update query on sqlite you need to specify the `SET` part of the statement as detailed here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Your query would be:
`UPDATE vault SET website = ?, username = ?, password = ?, day = ? WHERE [...]`

Use the `WHERE` clause to retrieve the row you want to update.

**EDIT**: this is how you should modify the section on lines 204:220.

```py
def save_new_password(input):
    website = str(text1.get("1.0", "end"))
    username = str(text2.get("1.0", "end"))
    password = str(text3.get("1.0", "end"))
    day = str(text4.get("1.0", "end"))
    insert_fields = """UPDATE vault SET website = ?, username = ?, password = ?, day = ? WHERE id = ?"""
    cursor.execute(insert_fields, [website, username, password, day, input])
    db.commit()
    text1.config(state="disabled")
    text2.config(state="disabled")
    text3.config(state="disabled")
    text4.config(state="disabled")
    password_vault()

password_save_button = tk.Button(my_frame, text="Save your updated information",
                                    command=partial(save_new_password, array[i][0]))
password_save_button.grid(column=6, row=i+4, pady=8, padx=10)
```

**EDIT2**: How to fix the question regarding updating only the last row. What is happening is that your functions are acting on the global scope text1, text2, text3 and text4. These variables are changing during the while loop and refer only the last assigned value. What i would change (without refactoring too much) is pass the variables with partial exactly as you did for the other variables.

So lines 151:155 would be:

```py
def edit_password(text1, text2, text3, text4):
     text1.config(state="normal")
     text2.config(state="normal")
     text3.config(state="normal")
     text4.config(state="normal")
```

and lines 202:220 would be:

```py
edit_button = tk.Button(my_frame, text="Update information", command=partial(edit_password, text1, text2, text3, text4))
edit_button.grid(column=5, row=i+4, pady=8, padx=10)

def save_new_password(input, text1, text2, text3, text4):
    website = str(text1.get("1.0", "end"))
    username = str(text2.get("1.0", "end"))
    password = str(text3.get("1.0", "end"))
    day = str(text4.get("1.0", "end"))
    insert_fields = """UPDATE vault SET website = ?, username = ?, password = ?, day = ? WHERE id = ?"""
    cursor.execute(insert_fields, [website, username, password, day, input])
    db.commit()
    text1.config(state="disabled")
    text2.config(state="disabled")
    text3.config(state="disabled")
    text4.config(state="disabled")
    password_vault()

password_save_button = tk.Button(my_frame, text="Save your updated information",
                                    command=partial(save_new_password, array[i][0], text1, text2, text3, text4))
```

Notice the changes on the edit call and on the save call.

BTW you also have an error on the line 176. `fetch_all()` returns an empty list and causes a non blocking exception. You should test on `len` like:

```py
if len(cursor.fetchall()) > 0:
   ...
```

Comment: That almost works.  I'm still a little confused about what to set  WHERE to. I just want the current row. I tried setting WHERE [id = ?] and I got an error.

Comment: The `[...]` was just a placeholder, the query would be `UPDATE vault SET website = ?, username = ?, password = ?, day = ? WHERE id = ?`. you would also need to set up your `save_new_password` like you did with your `remove_entry` function where you are using partial to send the id as an argument

Comment: I tried and no dice. can you show me what you mean?

Comment: edited the answer, adding the fix. I changed the query and added the partial in order to forward the id to the function `save_new_password`

Comment: Thank for your help. Do you have any ideas on how to answer the first question: edit_password only lets me edit the bottom row? I want edit_password to be able to change the state from "disabled" to "normal" on any given row that the edit_button is on.

Comment: added an **EDIT2** for that question. Let me know if what i explained is not clear!